# Loading view from XIB into ViewController and VIewCell

Tags: ios, swift, xib, nib

I have a XIB with a custom class *ProfileHeaderView*.
I also have *ProfileViewController* and *ProfileTableViewCell*, both with *IBOutlet profileHeader*.

What I want is to load nib into *profileHeader* . So far I do it by loading NIB and then adding it as a subview of *profileHeader* which I guess is not the best solution and i have to set frame manually.

```
let view = NSBundle.mainBundle().loadNibNamed("ProfileHeaderView", owner: self, options: nil).last as! ProfileHeaderView
view.setFrame(...)
self.profileHeaderView.addSubview(self.view)
```

What's the best way to achieve it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, create custom view class

```
class CustomView: UIView {

    // MARK: Custom View Initilization
    var view: UIView!

    func xibSetup() {
        view = loadViewFromNib()
        view.frame = bounds
        view.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizing.FlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizing.FlexibleHeight
        addSubview(view)
        //// additional setup here
    }
    func loadViewFromNib() -> UIView {
        let bundle = NSBundle(forClass: self.dynamicType)
        // set nibName to be xib file's name
        let nib = UINib(nibName: "CustomView", bundle: bundle)
        let view = nib.instantiateWithOwner(self, options: nil)[0] as! UIView
        return view
    }
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        xibSetup()
    }
    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        xibSetup()
    }

}
```

Second, in `CustomView.xib` set `File's owner` custom class to  `CustomView`

---

After, you've done. you can create the custom view programmatically.

```
let customView = CustomView(frame: frame)
self.view.addSubview(customView)
```

Or using storyboard, by drag UIView to ViewController and set UIView's custom class to `CustomView`